# When should I call $digest instead of $apply?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have seen both

`$rootScope.$apply();`

and

`$rootScope.$digest();`

being used inside a factory. However [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) say:

> Usually, you don't call $digest() directly in controllers or in
>   directives. Instead, you should call $apply() (typically from within a
>   directive), which will force a $digest().
>
> If you want to be notified whenever $digest() is called, you can
>   register a watchExpression function with $watch() with no listener.
>
> In unit tests, you may need to call $digest() to simulate the scope
>   life cycle.

One of the advantages of not calling `$digest` directly is to avoid running an infinite loop.

Are there any cases in which one should use `$digest` over `$apply` (apart from testing, as mentioned in the quote)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your application becomes sufficiently large enough that digests become prohibitively expensive, you can call digest on scopes that you're sure don't cause side-effects on other parts of your application.

For instance you may have introduced a jQuery calendar plugin, that you would ordinarily call $apply on to observe its bindings to a scope. This calendar might be for a feedback form so it is, so to speak, independent to the rest of your application, which may be a large real-time data feed that has thousands of watchers.

A scope.apply on your calendar would go through your whole application and do dirty checks on all your thousands of watchers for your real-time feed when it is unnecessary. In this situation, you should call $scope.$digest() because you know only the calendar model has changed.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Could you please include some resources backing what you're saying?

Comment: Source: me, I'm angular developer and I'm the resource - based on my experience

Answer (score 2):

I think the documentation is unhelpful here. As far as i know:

- `$digest` will process all watchers of the **current scope and its children**.
- `$apply()` is more or less a **wrapper around `$rootScope.$digest`** and thus will run a full digest on all scopes.

Unlike the doc says you can use both methods to pull an update from outside Angular into the digest cycle. As already said, `$apply` may invoke a full digest cycle, meaning `$rootScope.$digest()`. Calling `$digest` instead will most likely prevent that from happening and is better for performance.

If you want to be absolutely certain that Angular recognizes the change, use `$apply`. If you know what you are doing and only need to update the current scope (or its children) use `$digest`.

Comment: So there's no difference in calling `$rootScope.$digest()` or `$rootScope.$apply()`?

Comment: A slight but very important difference. Marked bold in my answer.

Comment: You say calling $digest is only likely to prevent a rootScope digest. Under what circumstances would a $digest call on a child scope trigger a rootscope digest?